# How large and bright has to be a spaceship so that you can see it with the naked eye moving at 0.99c near Pluto?

Tags: physics, astrophysics

Today someone looks up at the night sky unintentionally directly towards Pluto. There is a bright light which is impossible to mistake for a star, satellite or shooting star, as it's shaped like a flat line.

What he sees is a giant ancient arcship flying through the solar system at a distance of 33.18 astronomical units (distance Pluto today) with a speed of 0.99c. It's sphere shaped, but
it's big relative speed constracts it due to special relativity to a flat disk.
The ship is flying through the solar system plane at a right angle, so the observer looks at the edge of the disk, giving the impression of a glowing line in the sky.

[image: rough sketch of the scenario]

My question is:

1. How big (radius) has the ship to be that a human observer sees it as a line and not just a point?
2. How brightly has it to glow so its light is attention grabbing if looking casually at the night sky despite its length contraction?
3. Is 0.99c fast enough to keep it flat or does it has to be faster?

For the purpose of this question the observer is the only human on Earth. The ship doesn't accelerate or interact with Earth in any way except glowing, and it has no gravitational influence on the solar system due to handwavium-systems.

Comment: Should we assume that the ship's handwavium systems also prevent it from collapsing into a star? Because my guess is it has to be about as big as the sun. From Pluto's orbit, the sun looks pretty small, almost a dot, and you won't be able to resolve the line unless it looks more like a circle than a dot when standing still

Comment: How could speed make a useful difference, except against whether the watcher was lucky enough to be looking in the right place at the right time?

How are you not Asking members to do your (fairly simple) maths for you?

Comment: How could speed come into this? 

How could size (radius) make an observer see it as a line, not a point?

Does "attention grabbing" mean "bright" or what?

Whatever its length contraction, how could that keep it flat? Isn't flatness about height and in terms of contraction, quite unrelated to length? Else why would we not talk of shrinkage, not contraction? 

How could it matter the observer was the only human on Earth, or whether the ship accelerated or interacted with Earth in any way? 

Would you rather explain how handwavium means it has no gravitational influence, or drop that?

Comment: The Overlords finally come! More 100 years to they show themselves to us!

Comment: If this spaceship is colliding with cosmic dust and Kuiper belt objects, it would be very visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Unless you're looking through a telescope, really big.

If you just wanted to see a point-sized light, you could turn up the brightness to compensate for size. But you specifically want to see a shape - a line. This means the object needs to be big enough for that. It seems the human is looking at the sky with the nakes eye, so that's what I'll base my calculations on. Even before doing any math I can say that we can't see pluto with the naked eye, so any object must be bigger than that.

Finding the exact angular resolution of the human eye is not easy, but a good approximation is 1 arcminute (one 60th of a degree). Smaller than this and it's impossible to see as anything besides a point, or at all. To this we appply some simple trigonometry: tan(angle) = opposite/adjacent, or adjacent * tan(angle) = opposite. Adjescent here is distance to pluto, angle is half of an arcminute and opposite is radius of object. Plug in the numbers (using 33.18 AU for pluto distance), and you get a diameter of 0.00965167083 AU, which at 1.5 * 10^8 km/AU comes to about 1.5 * 10^7 km. So the object would be much bigger than  the sun (1.3927 * 10^6 km).

In conclusion, seeing any shape other than a point at that far of a distance requires mind-bogglingly large objects. Maybe try a telescope, or a closer orbit.

Comment: 1 a.u. is about 1.5E11 meters, which divided by 100 is about 1.5E9 meters or 1.5E6 kilometers.

Comment: ^so only marginally larger than the sun.

Comment: @AlexP You divide by 1000, as there is one thousand meters in a kilometer. Otherwise you are right, and I have updated my math. Still larger than the sun, but one order of magnitude instead of two.